# How to double check if a resource is actually being served through a site´s CDN service?

Tags: cdn, cloudflare

I am currently working on improving a site´s page loading speed.

The site is a local site offering many different recreational activities.

According to WebPageTest, the site is actually using a CDN service (Cloudflare).

But, I want to double-check whether or not certain resources are actually being served through the CDN.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches you could try :

Firstly, you could use https://www.cdnplanet.com/tools/cdnfinder/.   This will tell you what CDN is being used by the site.

Alternatively, you could try using a Chrome extension called IPvFoo, which will show you all of the IP addresses that the site is getting content from.

You can then use https://bgp.he.net to query who owns any of those IP addresses.

For reference, Cloudflare IP address ranges are available here :  https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/

Answer (score 0):

Using Cloudflare as an example, as mentioned in your question, you can verify if content was returned by the CDN using the Server HTTP response header.

```
server: cloudflare
```

But it should not vary unless you have something like a load balancer. Assuming you pointed your domain DNS to Cloudflare, all DNS requests should resolve to Cloudflare.